# Linq Query to find min and max in a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I am fetching the attendance details of employees in a datatable .
It looks like this

```
Day       SwipeTime
12/31/2012  11AM
12/31/2012  1PM
12/31/2012  7PM
12/31/2012  8PM
1/1/2012    2PM
1/1/2012    7PM
1/1/2012    8PM
1/2/2012    10AM
1/2/2012    8PM
```

I need to display the date and totalhours for an employee
where totalhours = lastswipe - firstwipe

my result would look like

```
Day TotalHours
12/31/2012  9
1/1/2012    6
1/2/2012    12
```

So i need to find min and max swipes grouped by date.
Please help me write the query

Comment: no field called swipetype as to whether ita a swipe in or swipe out?

Comment: What is the result if there is just one swipe in a day?

Comment: please tell me `Day` is a `DateTime.Date`

Comment: @naveen ..doesnt matter its just an example..i need to get min and max...@sweko : good observation..but i am not thinking about that now :)

Comment: @saddam bro : Day is DateTime.Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` to group by `date`. Then you could create a `Dictionary<DateTime,int>` where the key is the date and the value are the total-hours for that date:

```
Dictionary<DateTime,int> dateGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date)
    .Select(g => new{
        Date = g.Key, 
        TotalHours = g.Sum(r => 
               DateTime.ParseExact(r.Field<string>("SwipeTime"), 
                      "htt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Hour)
    }).ToDictionary(x => x.Date, x => x.TotalHours);
```

**Edit**: So, that was the `TotalHours` of the whole day, now the desired max-min calculation. You also have changed your desired timespan-format to "11:41 AM". Then i would use `DateTime.Parse(str).TimeOfDay` to get the timespan.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int> dateGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date)
.Select(g => new
{
    Date = g.Key,
    TotalHours = 
       (g.Max(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("SwipeTime")).TimeOfDay)
      - g.Min(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("SwipeTime")).TimeOfDay)).Hours
}).ToDictionary(x => x.Date, x => x.TotalHours);
```

Comment: I am getting this error :String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  Apparently my swipe format is like 11:41 PM....what should be the string format in this case?

Comment: @sajad: Edited my answer to take your max-min reuirement into account and your new date/timespan format.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer ordered list of times for day is created to avoid two things - parsing all rows twice, and creating two sets from parsed values to get max and min item. Also I do not parse day before grouping, because same date will have same string value.

```
var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("Day") into g
            let times = g.Select(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("SwipeTime")))
                         .OrderBy(t => t.TimeOfDay)
                         .ToList()
            select new
            {
                DateTime.Parse(g.Key).Date,
                (times.Last() - times.First()).TotalHours
            };
```

Result is a collection of anonymous objects with two properties `DateTime Date` and `double TotalHours`

Comment: You don't need `DateTime.ParseExact`, you can simply use `DateTime.Parse("11:41 AM")`.